# Create desktop folder electron

Tags: node.js, electron, fs

I'm using node `fs` to create a directory and then watch it in my electron app. Users can then use that directory to upload documents. I use `chokidar` to watch the directory for documents. This all works locally; `fs` creates the directory inside my app folder. I can drag and drop files in, everything works.

This doesn't work, however, when I deploy the app to windows. I've searched the filesystem and cannot find where this folder was created.

What I'd like to do is create the folder on their Desktop. It would be even cooler if I could react to movements of the folder (e.g. the user moves it to Documents).

Is there a way to

1. Create the folder on their desktop (both osx and windows)
2. Listen for when the folder has been moved to another location.

Thanks!

#### Update

Found a way to find their desktop directory

```
const dir = Path.join(require('os').homedir(), 'Desktop/whatever');
```

Is there a way to do number 2?

Comment: easily? no. not really.

Comment: Just look for the folder where you expect it to be and if it isn't there, ask the user to locate it.